# A field with precision 10, scale 2 must round to an absolute value less than 10^8

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, postgresql-9.3

I have a django-field `total_price` in `postgres` database version `9.3.11`.

Here is the code:

`total_value = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=100, default=0, max_digits=300)`

I want to convert it to proper 2 decimal place. So I wrote this:

`total_value = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, default=0, max_digits=10)`

### My migration file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models, migrations

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('my_table', '0040_my_table_skipped'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='my_table',
            name='total_value',
            field=models.DecimalField(default=0, 
                                      max_digits=10, 
                                      decimal_places=2),
        ),
    ]
```

When I run command `python manage.py migrate`

I get an error from postgresql:

`A field with precision 10, scale 2 must round to an absolute value less than 10^8.`

Comment: Is there any value in the `total_price` column in your database that has a value larger than or equal to 10^8?

Comment: Yes. Table is huge. Like thousands of rows. Example value is this 9.9900000000000002131628207280300557613372802734375000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: 9.99...whatever is *not* larger than 10^8; it's just ridiculously precise. Try and find the *maximum* value of that *column* (not the entire table). NB: thousands of rows is certainly not huge.

Comment: Okay. got it. Sorry I miss understood. I need to find the maximum value and then need to increase the max digits acording to that

Comment: Any luck solving your problem?

Answer (score 34):

As @sivakumar-r mentioned above, it's the precision and scale issue.

Let's see how the `Numeric(precision, scale)` works:

Suppose, if we have a column defined with `NUMERIC(10,3)`.

This means, we can only save 10 digits in total with 3 spaces after decimal point.

So the range you can save in this case is:
+9999999.999 to -9999999.999.

**One Solution Could be:**

Alter table column to use type `NUMERIC` without the precision and scale.

This will accept up to 131072 digits before the decimal point; up to 16383 digits after the decimal point. [As mentioned in postgres:11 Numeric types document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-numeric.html).

Answer (score 3):

Earlier you had decimal number like Number(300, 100). I think you have some data in this decimal field. Now you alter the decimal field to Number(10,2). So now you can only save max 99999999.99. But your old data is much more than this. Because earlier you can save decimal number of 300 max digits and 100 decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

### Reproduce this postgresql error:

```
ERROR:  numeric field overflow 
A field with precision 5, scale 4 must round to an absolute 
value less than 10^1
```

Create a postgresql table with a column with type: `numeric(4,4)` then try to insert data from another table that has a `numeric(5,4)` column type:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable( mycolumn numeric(5,4)); 
insert into mytable values(12.3456); 
CREATE TABLE mytable2( mycolumn numeric(4,4)); 
insert into mytable2 ( select * from mytable ); --Error thrown here
```

### Solution

Increase the space allotted to the numeric column receiving the data or define a custom cast function to make the number fit into its destination.